# Grails 2.4.5 - ERROR javascript.StrictErrorReporter - runtimeError with Geb download

Tags: grails, groovy, geb

My working environment is Grails 2.4.5 and I configured it in the following way:

BuildConfig.groovy:

```
...
def gebVersion = "0.12.1"
def seleniumVersion = "2.45.0"
dependencies {
    test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    test "org.gebish:geb-spock:$gebVersion"
}

plugins {
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55.2" // or ":tomcat:8.0.20"
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.8'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:2.4.3"
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.8.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
    test ":geb:$gebVersion"
 }
```

Basically, I just added Geb and selenium!

And during a functional test I'm trying to download a file

```
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec
import spock.lang.*

class FileDownloadSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

    def "DownloadController renders file"() {

        go ""

        expect: ""
        downloadContent("http://somethinghere.com/file.zip")
    }
 }
```

`

And I'm getting:

```
| Error 2015-08-06 16:35:26,598 [main] ERROR javascript.StrictErrorReporter  - runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: ':checked' error: Invalid selector: *:checked).] sourceName=[http://localhost:8080/deleteme/assets/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js?compile=false] line=[1228] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
| Error 2015-08-06 16:35:26,609 [main] ERROR javascript.StrictErrorReporter  - runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: ':enabled' error: Invalid selector: *:enabled).] sourceName=[http://localhost:8080/deleteme/assets/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js?compile=false] line=[1248] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
| Error 2015-08-06 16:35:26,648 [main] ERROR javascript.StrictErrorReporter  - runtimeError: message=[The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.] sourceName=[http://localhost:8080/deleteme/assets/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js?compile=false] line=[3521] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
| Error 2015-08-06 16:35:27,198 [JS executor for com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient@39779e4b] ERROR javascript.StrictErrorReporter  - runtimeError: message=[The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.] sourceName=[http://localhost:8080/deleteme/assets/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js?compile=false] line=[3521] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
| Error 2015-08-06 16:35:27,254 [JS executor for com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient@39779e4b] ERROR javascript.StrictErrorReporter  - runtimeError: message=[The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.] sourceName=[http://localhost:8080/deleteme/assets/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js?compile=false] line=[3521] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
```

Obviously, Grails is using the asset-pipeline plugin. Does anyone know if there is a conflict with geb + grails + asset-pipeline? Any idea of what is happening?